# Create a .NET DLL component in a separate process

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, memory, process

We have an ASP.NET application that uses a .NET component (which we created) that references an un-managed third party COM DLL that appears to be very leaky. The third party DLL is a 32-bit-only component that, under heavy use, allocates a lot of memory. Eventually we run into fatal errors that require the w3wp process hosting out component to shut down (usually via IISReset) presumably because more memory can't be allocated in the 32-bit process' memory space.

My question is, is there a relatively straightforward way to convert our ASP.NET application and/or .NET component to run out-of-process so that individual instances or pools of instances will run in separate processes and be 1) less constrained by the 32-bit memory limit; and 2) more able to clean up by terminating the host process? I think I can use System.Diagnostics.Process.Create to create a trivial shell of a process that can create and offer instances to a client. But I'm not sure how to establish a connection between the client and the server. Maybe I have to use WCF somehow instead, but then I have less control over how objects are pooled within processes right? And it seems like a lot of overhead in complexity just to get something running in a separate process. Advice on the simplest path would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Didn't it used to be really simple to create out-of-process COM components? Is there anything as simple in pure .NET?

Comment: Another option (one I prefer) is to use .NET remoting (which I find easier to use with remote objects).

Comment: The documentation for .NET remoting makes it appear to be going out of style and being replaced with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I think it easier to use IIS facilities as a crutch for such a poorly designed component. You can enable Recycling when certain amount of memory is used or run a web garden mode by setting more then one in Maximum Worker Processes under Process Model. These options are under Advanced Settings of the Application Pools in IIS manager.